# How to know if node-webkit app is running with Administrator/elevated privilege?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

How to determine if node-webkit is running with administrator privilege on Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use npm packages for any small task - this is very bad practice.

```
    var isElevated;

    try {
        child_process.execFileSync( "net", ["session"], { "stdio": "ignore" } );

        isElevated = true;
    }
    catch ( e ) {
        isElevated = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you can use the npm package [is-admin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-admin), to check if the node process is elevated.

```
const isAdmin = require('is-admin');

isAdmin().then(elevated => {
    if (elevated) {
        console.log('Elevated');
    } else {
        console.log('Not elevated');
    }
});
```

There is also a cross platform implementation called [is-elevated](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-elevated) which bundles elevation checks for Unix and Windows

Answer (score 0):

Using the [node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) module, you can call the following function to determine whether the current user has admin rights:

```
var wincmd = require('node-windows');

wincmd.isAdminUser(function(isAdmin){
  if (isAdmin) {
    console.log('The user has administrative privileges.');
  } else {
    console.log('NOT AN ADMIN');
  }
});
```

Comment: this seems to only check if the user is in the admin group but doesn't tell you if the process is elevated