# Check if electron app is launched with admin privileges on windows

Tags: windows, electron

Is there a way to check if an electron app is launched with the admin rights?

I only found **electron-sudo** lib to execute commands with admin privileges.

But I have **multiple** commands to execute and I do not want to prompt the user every time.

So how can I check if the app is **started** with admin privileges **using electron** ?

The best thing would be just to execute a command inside the software ex: .isAdminPrivilegesUsed (can be a script that is executed on Windows) that return true or false, and if false :

I will prompt the user that he has to restart the software with admin rights and close it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I checked into how to do this from Node and found this answer: [How to know if node-webkit app is running with Administrator/elevated privilege?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669244/how-to-know-if-node-webkit-app-is-running-with-administrator-elevated-privilege).

I checked into the answer, downloaded node-windows and tried it. The solution, however, brought up the UAC dialog and always responded with "The user has administrative privileges".

I dug into the node-windows code that handles the isAdminUser command and found that it tried to  run NET SESSION and, if does not have privilege, tries to run it elevated causing the UAC dialog.

I pulled out the part that does the elevate and ended up with this snippet:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
exec('NET SESSION', function(err,so,se) {
      console.log(se.length === 0 ? "admin" : "not admin");
    });
```

I tested this by running the application normally and with "Run as Administrator". The code above correctly displayed "not admin" when not run as administrator and "admin" when run as administrator.

This should work for the content of your .isAdminPrivilegesUsed method you referenced in the question.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! I use this code to display a popup to force the user to restart the soft with admin rights

Comment: It indeed works when i launch it from normal cmd, but did not in PowerShell =)

Answer (score 11):

You can now specify that an app should run with elevated privileges using the electron build tools:

### electron-builder

Add the following to your package.json:

```
  "build": {
    "win": {
      "requestedExecutionLevel": "highestAvailable"
    }
  },
```

`highestAvailable` or `requireAdministrator` available. For full details, see: https://www.electron.build/configuration/win.html#WindowsConfiguration-requestedExecutionLevel

### electron-packager

When you call `electron-packager` add the following command-line parameter:

```
--win32metadata.requested-execution-level=highestAvailable
```

`highestAvailable` or `requireAdministrator` available. For full details, see https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/master/interfaces/electronpackager.win32metadataoptions.html#requested_execution_level

### Note

These options make the program request elevated privileges rather than check whether the program is running with administrator privileges.

Comment: A very worthy "Note" because basically what this does is updates manifest. Manifest could be updated one again with lower privileges ;)

Comment: @NoobTW: I don't know anything about Windows Portable, but are you using a user with administrative privileges? Also try "requireAdministrator" instead of "highestAvailable".

Comment: That doesn't work for the latest version. See the issue https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2936

Answer (score 6):

If you are using electron-packager, just add `--win32metadata.requested-execution-level=requireAdministrator`. Eg:

`electron-packager app --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --win32metadata.requested-execution-level=requireAdministrator --overwrite`

Comment: For electron-packager users, this answer was extremely helpful. The `requireAdministrator` option is technically [in the docs somewhere](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/master/interfaces/electronpackager.win32metadataoptions.html#requested_execution_level), but not easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

A popular Electron app has a solution for this problem
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

In the [package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/package.json) file they have two useful dependencies:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-is-elevated
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vscode/sudo-prompt

They check to see if permissions are elevated using `native-is-elevated`, and if not, prompt for an admin password using `sudo-prompt`.

You can read the source code for the process here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/8845f89c1e4183b54126cd629cd45c8f0f7549f2/src/vs/platform/native/electron-main/nativeHostMainService.ts#L491

I have created an example Electron app using this approach here:
https://github.com/kmturley/electron-runas-admin

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question. Another option to solve this problem is to force the application to be executed as administrator.

This can be done by updating the manifest file for the application, one guide on how to do this with Electron is here: http://layer0.authentise.com/electron-and-uac-on-windows.html

Comment: Thanks!  I like this option !

Comment: Please be warned that manifest could be updated one again with lower privileges ;)